# 1-1 Mapping in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I have a variable $Y$=Control=$C$ and three variables:

- Fraud := $F$
- Error := $E$
- Waste := $W$

all numerical variables. I am studying the effect of control methods on each of $F,E,W$, as well as on the combination of the three.

To study the three efficiently variables simultaneously, I am then modeling $\frac{P(A)}{1-P(A)}$
Where $A$ = the event where $F=E=W=1$ , so that $A = A_F \cup A_E \cup A_W$ , where $A_F$ is the event that $F=1$ , etc.

For this last, to study the effects of control on "general efficiency", I am trying to do a logistic regression where I combine all measures of efficiency; $F,E,W$ into a single variable, say $X$, which I define as $X=\frac{1}{3}(F+E+W)$ and then I regress $C$ against $X$. Is there a standard way of doing this? I am not sure that the $F,E,W$ are pairwise independent. If I have the cutoff values, say $F=F_0, E=E_0, W=W_0$ (meaning I decide that $F=1$ if $F>F_0$, $E=1$ if $E>E_0, W=1$ if $W>W_0$) , is the cutoff value of X the average of the three cutoff values?

Are there any other considerations for this case? Should I address the issue of the pairwise independence of $F,E,W$?

Comment: Kindly clarify - is C the dependent variable or X?

Comment: Sure. C is the dependent variable. I am trying to see how to merge three independent variables : F,E,W into a single independent variable defined as X= (1/3) (F+E+W).